# Change style of content depending on another css property value

Tags: html, css

Say, I want to change the background color of all the content in a paragraph that ***does not*** have any `text-decoration` (like bold, underline, etc.). Is it possible to do it just using CSS with a some kind of syntax like this?

```
p[text-decoration=none] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

A sample HTML content that this CSS should be applied will be something like this:

```
<p class="special">Yellow background <b>default background for paragraph</b> yellow
again <i>default</i> once again yellow.</p>
```

Requirements for the above to work:

1. Do not add style and/or class attributes to the paragraph contents, i.e., to `<b>`, `<i>`, etc.
2. Do not change the styles for `<b>`, `<i>`, etc.
3. `Background-color` should be specified for any content (HTML or CSS-style based) that ***does not*** have any `text-decoration`.
4. The parent of `<p>` may have a *custom* `background-color`, so elements like `<b>` or `<i>` should assume *that* color.

Comment: Are the styles specified in css or through the styles attribute?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I added sample HTML that this CSS should be applied. Is it clear?

Comment: As CSS is not a scripting language this isn't possible. Your example selector would look for a paragraph with an attribute named `text-decoration`.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, This can be done through css, in the case when `text-decoration` is specified through the styles attribute. Like this - `<p style="text-decoration: none">`.On vanilla css you won't do it. Are you allowed javascript?

Comment: No, I don't want to use JavaScript. My question was on whether there is a CSS way to do this.

Comment: Do you need such a result? - https://ibb.co/py0nm37

Comment: Yes. But I added some clarifications to the end of my question.

Comment: parent of tag `p` has background color?

Comment: Most of the times, yes.

Comment: I can offer only two solutions - 1. Use css variables; 2 - Use javascript. You **cannot** solve this problem with a simple css.

Comment: OK; thanks. I was only  curious whether there was a simple solution that I was not aware of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to make the absolutely correct decision according to your requirements with the help of CSS. But you can apply a little trick, which is to use the CSS variables declared inside `:root`.

The principle is to use the same background color for the background of the main parent and the background of tags `b` and `i`. You need to declare a variable like this:

```
:root {
    --backColor: yellowgreen;
}
```

Next, using function `var()`, assign the declared variable for rules `background-color`, `body` tags (parent), `b` and `i`:

```
background-color: var(--backColor);
```

In pseudo-class `:is()`, you need to specify tags (`b` and `i`) for which the background color of the *variable* will be assigned.

```css
:root {
    --backColor: yellowgreen;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--backColor);
}

p {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}

p * {
    display: inherit;
}

p *:is(b, i) {
    background-color: var(--backColor);
}
```

```html
<p class="special">Yellow background <b>default background for paragraph</b> yellow again <i>default</i> once again yellow.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I had `background-image` for the `body`, `background-color` for the `p`, but I was able to do the necessary modifications with success. Can you give some explanations (in your answer) about the need of use for the `display` property. Also what is the difference of `p *:is(b, i)` from `p>b, p>i`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, I used property `display` simply to align tags (this does not affect the mechanism of the code's functionality), i.e. you can do without property `display`. With `:is()` you can list all the required selectors in one parenthesis `:is(a, b, c ... n) { code }` - this is convenient and a minimum of css code. In the case of `p>a`, you would have to write rule `p>a`, `p>b`, `p>c` ... `p>n { code }`  for each selector.

Comment: So, the CSS code in my case becomes something like: `:root { --bi: url(../images/back2.jpg); }
body { background-image: var(--bi); }
p {  background-color: yellow; }
p>b, p>i {  background-image: var(--bi); }`.